# Fatal error: Call to a member function set_charset() on a non-object in /home/vhosts/galgonews.xp3.biz/includes/connect_database.php on line 3

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am working with my android app admin panel on php , i have uploaded the files online and when i open the website its giving me php error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function set_charset() on a non-object in /home/vhosts/galgonews.xp3.biz/includes/connect_database.php on line 3
```

here is my **connect_database.php** code :

> include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/variables/variables.php'); 
>   $connect->set_charset('utf8');

here is my **close_database.php**

> include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/variables/variables.php');
>
> $connect->close();

here is my **variables.php**

```
$host ="host";
$user ="username";
$pass ="_passhere_";
$database = "database";

// variables.php
$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

/* check connection */
if ($connect->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $connect->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

**Also it is working super fine on localhost xampp without any error !!**

Comment: put a `var_dump( $connect)` before `$connect->set_charset('utf8');`

Comment: enable `display_errors`, and check if `include` trigger a `warning`.

Comment: Work backwards - it tells you you're calling `set_charset` on a non object. You're doing that on `$connect` - using logic, you deduce that `$connect` isn't an object. You go back to where `$connect` is defined and you start debugging. Also, I would like to point out why XAMPP is bad for development - because the environment never matches what's going to be on the live server, which is why you could invest some time in researching alternative solutions (Homestead vagrant machine for example).